# Twist of a group Hopf-algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-schemes, hopf-algebras, reference-request

Let $G$ be a finite group with identity element $e$, and $C[G]$ the ring of complex-valued functions on $G$, with pointwise addition and multiplication.  Then $C[G]$ is naturally a Hopf algebra, with comultiplication, counit, and antipode given by
$$[\Delta(f)](g_1, g_2) = f(g_1 \cdot g_2), [\epsilon(f)] = f(e), [S(f)](g) = f(g^{-1}),$$
for all $f \in C[G]$, $g, g_1, g_2 \in G$.  Here we identify $C[G] \otimes_C C[G]$ with $C[G \times G]$ in the usual way.

If $\chi \in Z^2(G, C^\times)$ is a normalized (meaning $\chi(g,1) = \chi(1,g) = 1$) two-cocycle, then one can "twist" the coalgebra structure on $C[G]$, defining new comultiplication and antipode by
$$\Delta_\chi(f) = \chi \cdot \Delta(f) \cdot \chi^{-1}, S_\chi f = U (S f) U^{-1},$$
where $U = \sum_i \chi_i^{(1)} (S \chi_i^{(2)})$.

This, according to Theorem 2.3.4 of Shahn Majid's "Foundations of quantum group theory," produces a new Hopf algebra structure.  It's typically called $C_\chi[G]$ (though my notation differs slightly from Majid's).  Here, I think that we are viewing $\chi$ -- a priori a function from $G \times G$ to $C^\times$ -- as an element $\sum_i \chi_i^{(1)} \otimes \chi_i^{(2)} \in C[G] \otimes_C C[G]$, identifying complex-valued functions on $G \times G$ with elements of $C[G] \otimes C[G]$ as usual, and for some reason $U$ is invertible in the ring $C[G] \otimes C[G]$.

Now for the question...

The Hopf algebra $C_\chi[G]$ obtained through this process is still a commutative Hopf algebra over $C$; only the antipode and comultiplication were changed.  So $Spec(C_\chi[G])$ is an affine group scheme over $C$, whose $C$-points are in bijection with the elements of $G$.

So... what is this group scheme?!  Or have I messed something up in this construction?  It seems very odd to me, since the cocycle should -- group theoretically -- produce a central extension of $G$ by $C^\times$, and I don't know how such a thing would be encoded in a group scheme whose $C$-points are in bijection with $G$.  Any references for this group scheme?

Comment: I don't understand, multiplication in $\mathbb C[G]\bigotimes\mathbb C[G]$ is commutative so $\Delta_\chi$ looks like it is equal to $\Delta$.

Comment: @Torsten:  Of course... I think you are right.  I'll put it down as an answer.  It's just weird that Majid makes something of this example in his book -- it threw me off completely.

Comment: Note that you can twist the coalgebra structure (just not by the formula above), it won't be a Hopf algebra though.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $H$ is a Hopf algebra over a field $k$.

There are two dual notions that we can use in order to deform $H$, one is Drinfeld's twists and the other is Hopf 2-cocycle.

(**Remark:** Hopf 2-cocycles also are related with Hopf-Galois theory, since there exists a biyective correspondence between Hopf 2-cocycle and cleft Galois object (see [Hopf bigalois extensions](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~schauen/papers/hbe.ps)), and for finite dimensional Hopf algebras, the classification of Hopf 2-cocycles is the same as the classification of Galois object.)

A 2-cocycles over $H$ (also called Hopf 2-coycles) is a linear map $\sigma:H\otimes H\to k$, invertible w.r.t the convolution product, and such that $\sigma(a_1, b_1)\sigma(a_2b_2, c) = \sigma(b_1, c_1)\sigma(a, b_2c_2).$  Using Hopf 2-cocycles you can get a new Hopf twisting the multiplication: $a\cdot_\sigma b = \sigma(a_1,b_1)a_2b_2\sigma^{-1}(a_3,b_3)$ and using the original comultiplication. As an example, for the group algeba $kG$, a Hopf 2-cocycle is the same as an usual 2-cocycle, where $G$ acts trivialy on $k^*$. In this case each twisting is again $kG$.

Now, for the Hopf algebra $k^G$ all is diferent, Hopf 2-cocycles are more complicated and interesting (see [Movshev](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=faa&paperid=723&option_lang=eng) and [C.G and Medina](http://lanl.arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1006/1006.3872v1.pdf) for a classification). In this case the deformations are not trivial, and you get examples of non-commutative and non-cocommutative Hopf algebras (See [C.G. and Natale](http://www.mathjournals.org/mrl/2007-014-006/2007-014-006-004.pdf) for concrete examples of non-trivial deformations).

Answer (score 3):

**This is wrong for silly reasons...**

Since you are using complex coefficients and the group is finite, all $2$-cocycles are coboundaries. So your twisted group algebra is simply isomorphic to the original group algebra: you don't get anything new.

Comment: I'm confused, aren't the coefficients in the multiplicative group and not the additive group (see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfel'd+twist for a formula that's certainly written multiplicatively).

Comment: Urgh, you are right!

Answer (score 2):

The Hope algebra arising from this "twist" is just the original Hopf algebra, since multiplication is commutative, so $\Delta = \Delta_\chi$ and $S = S_\chi$.  So it's a pretty dumb question, after all.

Then again, it makes me think that I'm not twisting the Hopf algebra correctly.  After all, one can twist the multiplication in the *group algebra* $CG$ to obtain a (still cocommutative) Hopf algebra $C_\chi G$ algebra that's honestly different from $CG$.  And one can take the dual, to obtain $(C_\chi G)^\ast$.  That's probably what I want to do, and I should probably make it a new question.

Comment: The fact that Majid(?) denotes by $C\left[G\right]$ what most of the world calls $C^G$ isn't useful either...

Comment: Anyway, if you want a nontrivial twist, then you must either twist the multiplication of a non-cocommutative bialgebra, or twist the comultiplication of a non-commutative bialgebra. Either way, I think the result is (in general) neither commutative nor cocommutative, so there shouldn't be an algberaic group interpretation. Or do I get it wrong?

Comment: Well, you can twist the multiplication of the noncommutative (if $G$ is nonabelian) bialgebra $CG$ as I mentioned above -- just put $g_1 \cdot_\chi g_2 = \chi(g_1, g_2) \cdot g_1 \cdot g_2$.  This produces $C_\chi G$, which is still cocommutative.

Similarly, I suppose that one can twist the comultiplication on $C[G]$ -- probably not by the formula I had in my original question.  But probably matching the dual of $C_\chi G$ as I put in this answer.

Comment: Are you sure this twist will be a bialgebra? The twist that I know goes like this: $x\cdot_{\sigma} y=\sigma(x_{(1)},y_{(1)})x_{(2)}y_{(2)}\sigma^{-1}(x_{(3)},y_{(3)})$. If you do this to a cocommutative algebra, it doesn't change.

Comment: @Grinberg:  Argh!  Too many possibilities.  What you describe seems like the twist dicsussed in Prop. 2.3.8 of Majid's book.  That would seem to twist the function algebra $C[G] = C^G$, since $\sigma$ is a normalized two-cocycle for the group if and only if its a counital 2-cocycle for the function algebra.  So this explains how to obtain a not-necessarily commutative twist of the function algebra.  Very good, I think -- and it explains why you don't get the function algebra of a group scheme.

Comment: I THINK that what I describe is the twist discussed in Majid's Prop 2.3.4 (except that I don't care about $\mathcal R$, while Majid doesn't care about bialgebras which are not quasitriangular Hopf) up to dualization. What you describe seems more like a crossed product than like a twist.

Comment: There are too many duals for me to follow.  Are you twisting the multiplication in the function algebra $C[G]$ or the group algebra $CG$ (to use Majid's notation)?  I'll try to work it out by hand to see what works...

Comment: Twisting multiplication in $C[G]$ doesn't change anything; twisting multiplication in $C^G$ makes it neither coco- nor commutative (at least I don't see a reason why it should). Make your choice ;)

Comment: I'll take the latter.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

In one case you will always get a group isomorphic to the group you started with, namely if your cocycle is symmetric. Actually in http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1412 Theorem 3.2 proves that all symmetric cocycles on a cocommutative, compact quantum group are trivial. A quantum group is to be understood in the von Neumann algebraic sense there, but for finite groups this point of view is equivalent to the Hopf algebraic $\mathbb{C}G$.